# How can I diagnose hangs on the UI thread in my application?

Tags: wpf, performance, rendering

I'm building a WPF desktop application whose UI, while dynamic, doesn't seem to me like it should be particularly demanding.  A typical user control in this application implements an expander that contains a two-column grid, where one column contains labels and the other contains text boxes or combo boxes.  The XAML for the expander's content looks like this:

```
<DockPanel Style="{StaticResource Style_ExpandedGridRowView}"
           Focusable="False">
    <DockPanel.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:BooleanFieldViewModel}">
            <local:GridBooleanField DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ChoiceFieldViewModel}">
            <local:GridChoiceField DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CodeLookupFieldSingleSelectionViewModel}">
            <local:GridCodeLookupField DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CodeLookupFieldMultipleSelectionViewModel}">
            <local:GridCodeLookupMultiSelectField DataContext="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CurrencyFieldViewModel}">
            <local:GridCurrencyField DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DateFieldViewModel}">
            <local:GridDateField DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:NotesFieldViewModel}">
            <local:GridNotesField DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:NumberFieldViewModel}">
            <local:GridNumberField DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TextFieldViewModel}">
            <local:GridTextField DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TimeFieldViewModel}">
            <local:GridTimeField DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DockPanel.Resources>
    <AdornerDecorator>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Fields, Mode=Default}"
                      Focusable="False">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                                Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </AdornerDecorator>
</DockPanel>
```

I've profiled my view model, and it takes less than 100 ticks to enumerate the `Fields` property, which contains fewer than 15 items.

It's taking something on the order of **20-30 seconds** for the expander to render its contents when I expand it.

During this time, the application is totally unresponsive.  This gets written to the output window, about one message every 4-5 seconds:

```
The thread '<No Name>' (0x21b0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1c54) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1c7c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x2638) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1bf0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Once the contents finally renders, I can open and close the expander with no perceivable delay.

The delay happens whether I'm using a debug or a release build, and whether I'm running in the IDE or from the desktop.

I've tried building against different versions of the .NET framework, to no avail.

I would speculate that what's happening here is some kind of deadlock in the rendering thread.  I mean, I can't think of any way that a CPU running instructions at 2GHz could possibly spend thirty seconds figuring out how to arrange 30 rectangles on a screen.  But I can't see any way that I have any control over that.

How can I diagnose the cause of this problem?  And, of course, fix it?  As you might imagine, this is a project-killing bug if I can't get it fixed.

**Edit:**

I should add that one thing I've tried, to no avail, is to disable hardware acceleration as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx#overview).  This has no perceivable effect.  I also tried using the reference rasterizer, only it's so slow that I can't even get my application to the point where it starts hanging.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?  I'm having a very similar problem with Silverlight, in almost every respect.  The only difference is that the hang does not occur consistently.

Answer (score 0):

How many items do you have in your `ItemsControl`? Have you tried using a `VirtualizingStackPanel` in your `ItemsPanelTemplate`?

Comment: I have a whopping 15 items in the control.  Like I said, there's no way the CPU is working hard at figuring where to put 30 rectangles.  Also, I finally got access to another machine that I could put this app on, and it rendered with no visible delay.